# Best practices in deep learning to use the same activation throughout the layers

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Are there any rules or best practices in Deep Learning to use the same activation function throughout the layers expected may be for the Output layer.

E.g., if I am using ReLu in one layer, is there any rule or best practice to use Relu throughout the network, or can I use Tan or any other activation function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, ReLU can make your network training convergence faster. See also this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126238/what-are-the-advantages-of-relu-over-sigmoid-function-in-deep-neural-networks). Therefore, if there are no additional considerations, you may want to stick to ReLU activation in all the layers.